# array operation giving me merged table

Tags: arrays, r

So, I made 10 matrix of 10X1 dimension, one of them looks like this,

```
chains <- array(NA, dim = c(10, 1, 10))
chains

, , 10

    [,1]
[1,]   NA
[2,]   NA
[3,]   NA
[4,]   NA
[5,]   NA
[6,]   NA
[7,]   NA
[8,]   NA
[9,]   NA
[10,]   NA
```

However, I want to keep last 6 observations from each matrix,
so I did,

```
   chains <-chains[5:10,,]
   chains

        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

suddenly it gives me one table, which gives me dimensional error on later algorithm,

i still want my "chain" array looks like this,
    , , 7

```
     [,1]
[1,]   NA
[2,]   NA
[3,]   NA
[4,]   NA
[5,]   NA
[6,]   NA


, , 8

    [,1]
[1,]   NA
[2,]   NA
[3,]   NA
[4,]   NA
[5,]   NA
[6,]   NA


, , 9

    [,1]
[1,]   NA
[2,]   NA
[3,]   NA
[4,]   NA
[5,]   NA
[6,]   NA


, , 10

    [,1]
[1,]   NA
[2,]   NA
[3,]   NA
[4,]   NA
[5,]   NA
[6,]   NA
```

I apologize for the bad formatting,
any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I confirmed if i have more than 1 column in each matrix, I get the desired result. R gives me merged table only when I have 1 column in each matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need `drop=FALSE` to prevent the subset from dropping the dimensions

```
chainsN <- chains[5:10,,,drop=FALSE]
str(chainsN)
#logi [1:6, 1, 1:10] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

It is mentioned in the help page of `?Extract`

> drop -
>   For matrices and arrays. If TRUE the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension